# Shrinking Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

firstly i have absolutely no idea what i'm doing and have managed to piece together bits from the intranet to make an web page for my works intranet.

When its opened it displays fine and the links work as intended however, the content of the page keeps automatically minimising until its almost disappears completely. Refreshing the page sets it back to full screen.

Here is what i have so far - Probably going to make a few people laugh as its more than likely all sorts of wrong hahaha : )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <body>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box
      }

      /* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
      body,
      html {
        height: 1000px;
        margin: auto;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }

      /* Style tab links */
      .tablink {
        background-color: #9AE0F4;
        color: White;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 20%;
      }

      .tablink:hover {
        background-color: #777;
      }

      /* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
      .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 100px 20px;
        height: 100%;
      }

      #Home {
        background-color: #85C1E9;
      }

      #Standard {
        background-color: #C49AF4;
      }

      #Niche {
        background-color: #FC9A70;
      }

      #Bike {
        background-color: #F9B7FF;
      }

      #FCA {
        background-color: Pink;
      }

    </style>
 

  

    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, '#85C1E9')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Standard', this, '#C49AF4')">Standard</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Niche', this, '#FC9A70')">Niche</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Bike', this, '#F9B7FF')">Bike</button>
    <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('FCA', this, 'Pink')">FCA</button>

    <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">

        <style>
          a:link,
          a:visited {
            color: Black;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 20px 25px;
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            width: 240px;
            height: 80px;
            top: 0px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            border: 5px #85C1E9;
          }

        </style> 

<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #E5E4E2 "> Audit Summaries </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #00FFFF "> Client Unsubscribe </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #4863A0 "> Company Information </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #728C00 "> EPA Page </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #FDD017 "> Extensions </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #9172EC "> Fire Procedure </a>

</div>

<div id="Standard" class="tabcontent">


<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #E5E4E2 "> Audit Summaries </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #00FFFF "> Client Unsubscribe </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #4863A0 "> Company Information </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #728C00 "> EPA Page </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #FDD017 "> Extensions </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #9172EC "> Fire Procedure </a>


</div>

<div id="Niche" class="tabcontent">


<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #E5E4E2 "> Audit Summaries </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #00FFFF "> Client Unsubscribe </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #4863A0 "> Company Information </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #728C00 "> EPA Page </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #FDD017 "> Extensions </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #9172EC "> Fire Procedure </a>


</div>

<div id="Bike" class="tabcontent">

 
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #E5E4E2 "> Audit Summaries </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #00FFFF "> Client Unsubscribe </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #4863A0 "> Company Information </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #728C00 "> EPA Page </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #FDD017 "> Extensions </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #9172EC "> Fire Procedure </a>


</div>

<div id="FCA" class="tabcontent">



<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #E5E4E2 "> Audit Summaries </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #00FFFF "> Client Unsubscribe </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #4863A0 "> Company Information </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #728C00 "> EPA Page </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #FDD017 "> Extensions </a>
<a href=" http://intranet3000/ " target="_blank" style="background: #9172EC "> Fire Procedure </a>



</div>

<script>

function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

</script>
</body>
</head> 
</html>
```

Then after this there are loads of hyperlinks to pages throughout the works intranet.

Thanks in advance and any responses please bear in mind, i have no clue what i'm doing and am quote astonished i have got this far : )

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `<head>`tags in one page, and you can't have a `<head>` tag coming after `<body>` tag which you didn't bother closing. Nor did you close your `<div>` tag. Start with that. You need to clean up the code and it's best to seperate the CSS into a different file and link it to the index.html with a `<link>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now only have one head tag and it comes before the body tag which is closed at the very bottom after all the hyperlinks under each tab. I will look at separating the CSS into a different file and link it like you suggest but need to google how to do this, when i say i don't have a clue, i'm being very honest : )

Comment: Does it work now? You had a `<head>`tag INSIDE your `<body>` after another `<head>` tag and this could do lots of weird stuff. But unless you have other surprises at the bottom of your code - this should be fine.

Comment: It doesn't work, my work policy has all intranet pages to open in compatibility view, so i'm sure its something to do with this, If i open it from its source and not published on the intranet it works perfectly. I have edited the post with the whole content but slimmed down the hyperlinks so you just get the the basics.